# ASP.NET website too slow while debug=false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a performance issue with my ASP.NET MVC3 application, 
I noticed that the pages are retrieved very slowly (~30sec per request) when a put debug="false" in the web.config file.
If I keep debug="true" the loading & navigation are not slow at all.
It sounds very strange and I didn't find a similar problem in the web.

here is the compilation section of the web.config :

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

I'm using IIS Express 7.0 on my local machine and IIS 6 on the production server (same issue)

Comment: I have this same weird problem, setting `debug="false"` actually slows my rendering down by a factor of 3!